# SwiftMailer - using with Google Application-specific password & 2-step verification

Tags: php, email, gmail, swiftmailer

I am using the PHP mail function to send an email on a contact form that doesn't work on the live server - having checked the logs I see the following :-

```
Application-specific password required
```

Clearly I need to setup an Google Application-specific password and have this communicate to my email script. I am going to change the current mail function to use SwiftMailer instead - can anyone explain where I would setup the Application-specific password with the SwiftMailer library to ensure emails are always sent.

Comment: Just where you enter the usual SMTP password I think

Comment: Thanks @Pekka웃 - that did the trick i'll happily accept your answer although I think you may need to enter it using the "Answer Your Question" button below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the application specific password as the SMTP password when you authenticate.

Application specific passwords are a fallback for those applications that can't use [two-step verification.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744?hl=en)